# Recursive traversal of multidimentional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

Consider:

```
array(0 => array('id'=>'1', 'element1'=>'value1', 'element2'=>'value2'));
```

Now consider:

```
array(0 => ( array('id'=>'1')), 
      1 => ( array('element1'=>'value1')), 
      2 => ( array('element2'=>'value2'))
);
```

What would be the best way to traverse the first array to create the second array above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any further qualifications as to the logic that needs to be applied, this will do:

```
$array2 = array_chunk($array1[0], 1, true);
```

See http://php.net/array_chunk

Comment: Yes - I've tested it and that works perfectly.  Thank you. I will accept the answer when I am able (SO tells me I can accept an answer in 7 minutes!)